# Gromov-Witten invariants

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, topology

I'm a mathematician studying Schubert calculus, and I'm out to compute the [Gromov-Witten invariants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%E2%80%93Witten_invariant) of the complete flag manifold. Well, I actually already know how to compute them, but only in a way that involves cancellation, and the goal is to masterfully cancel everything and have only a formula that describes what's left.

I've heard this has some relationship to quantum field theory. I know very little physics other than what an enthusiast would read in a popular science book, but I do have some interest in the relationship of the problem I will spend my life failing to solve (far easier problems have been unsolved for 136 years) to reality. If anyone could give a brief overview of why physicists care about Gromov-Witten invariants I would appreciate it.

Comment: One can think of Gromov-Witten invariants as scattering amplitudes in a 'topological' version of a string theory, known as the topological A-model. This theory is a subsector of a physical string theory known as type IIA string theory. Intuitively, Gromov-Witten invariants of a space X study pseudoholomorphic maps from a Riemann surface (of a certain genus and possibly with punctures) to X; and in string theory, maps from a punctured Riemann surface to a manifold representing spacetime is just a possible string scattering process, with the punctures representing incoming/outgoing strings.

Comment: The pseudoholomorphic condition comes about since it gives the classical configurations of the A-model about which quantum perturbations manifest.

Comment: @MeerAshwinkumar It seems "Gromov-Witten invariant" is not quite a standardized term. The Wikipedia article has it being a rational number, whereas the Gromov-Witten invariants I know of are polynomials in variables $q_1,\ldots,q_n$ with integer coefficients. It does say that there are variations on the definition.

Comment: I believe the definition used in physics is the former. In any case perhaps you should take a look at Witten's papers 'Topological Sigma Models' and 'Mirror Manifolds and Topological Field Theory'. The monograph 'Mirror Symmetry' (which is available online) is also helpful, take a look at chapter 16 for a treatment of the topological A-model. The math section of the book does discuss Gromov-Witten invariants, see chapter 26. As you can see the definition there is given as an integral.

Comment: @MeerAshwinkumar I see. What I'm computing is the "potential" in the small quantum cohomology ring, which is derived from the three-point invariants, so the invariants are actually the coefficients of the polynomials, not the entire polynomial. (Boy do I feel dumb.) This stuff also explains why some Schubert calculus papers have the (to me, then) puzzling convention of using integral symbols to denote intersection numbers. Clearly I was unaware they could actually be computed by an explicit integral.

Comment: That is interesting, I did not know that the Gromov-Witten invariants were the coefficients of a polynomial. I should mention a very nice essay by Mina Aganagic, 'String theory and Math: Why this Marriage May Last', section 2 introduces Gromov-Witten invariants, and 2.1 is an answer to your original question. I believe other parts of the essay may also be helpful for you.

Comment: I think you may be able to find a physics paper which discusses Gromov-Witten invariants for complete flag manifolds, this could be it  http://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.1761.

Comment: @MeerAshwinkumar What do you know, a professor who taught a course in algebraic geometry that I took is cited in that paper. Thanks for all the help.